# Can't access discovery server through api gateway

Tags: spring, spring-boot, security, microservices

I have written a spring boot micro service application with spring security via keyclock server.

My eureka api gateway and micro service applications has able to talk to discovery server but I can't access the discovery console. it's giving 401 error.

here is my SecurityConfig.java in discovery server

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig  {

    @Value("${app.eureka.username}")
    private String username;
    @Value("${app.eureka.password}")
    private String password;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        return http.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth ->
                        auth.requestMatchers("/eureka/**").authenticated()
                )
                .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        UserDetails userDetails = User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
                .username(username)
                .password(password)
                .roles("USER")
                .build();
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(userDetails);
    }
}
```

it is able to resolve http://eureka:password@localhost:8761/eureka

but I am not able open http://localhost:8080/eureka/web ( routed through api gateway )

neither direct access to discovery server on http://localhost:8761

your help is appreciated.

I am expecting two type of authentication

1: through the discovery client running on each micro service

eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://eureka:password@localhost:8761/eureka

the above one  is working

2. through web browser to open discovery server console via api gateway at http://localhost:8080/eureka/web

or directly http://localhost:8761

this is not working. getting 401 error